# how can i take time.ctime away from time.ctime

Tags: python, time

```
Distance=200

import time

Time_started=time.ctime()
question=(input("has car gone pass sensor 1 \n:"))
if question=="yes":
        print ("the time is",Time_started,"seconds")

Time_ended=time.ctime()
question2=(input("has car gone pass sensor 2 \n:"))
if question2=="yes":
    print ("the time is",Time_ended,"seconds")
print ("")

Time_taken= (time.ctime() - Time_started)

print ("it took %f1 seconds" % Time_taken , "to travel 200m" )
```

i want to know if it is possible to take time.ctime away from each other to get the seconds by themselves

Comment: Is there a reason why you used specifically time.ctime? Because time.time() would return time in seconds (floating point).

Comment: there is no specific reason except for the fact that i prefer the way time.ctime is set out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `time.time()` and `time.ctime(secs)`

```
Time_started=time.time()
```

If you want to convert that to something user friendly, you can do:

```
print ("the time is",time.ctime(Time_started))
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not to use time.time() instead of time.ctime()?

Comment: i prefer the way time.ctime is set out. this is for my computer science coursework and i want to make it user friendly

Comment: This is ok for displaying time, but not for the timedelta. Also, take a look at datetime module.

Answer (score 0):

You said you only wanted time.ctime because it is user friendly, so you can do this:

Use `time.time()` to initialize `Time_started` and `Time_ended`, and use them whenever you need to calculate something (e.g., the difference between them).
But when you want to print the time to the user, use `time.ctime(Time_started)` or `time.ctime(Time_ended)`. time.ctime will then return a pretty string that describes the time you supplied it with.

Comment: is it possible for you to show me the code for this